# "-includeresource" in JAR Manifest inside Gradle build file

Tags: java, jar, osgi, dotcms

In [build.gradle](https://github.com/dotCMS/core/blob/master-3.1/docs/examples/osgi/com.dotcms.custom.spring/build.gradle) for the dotCMS OSGi custom Spring example, there is a line in the JAR manifest:

```
instruction '-includeresource', 'spring=spring, libs'
```

Is this a typo? Is '-includeresource' supposed to be 'Include-Resource'? I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on this.

Sorry if this is obvious. I am new to Gradle and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-includeresource` is an [bnd](http://bnd.bndtools.org/) instruction.  Per [the documentation](http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/820-instructions.html), it is used to:

> Include resources from the file system